# How do you take a text file and change split it into data usable for a machine learning classifier?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

for this practice exercise I'm only supposed to use numpy so I can't just use scikit learn.

I've loaded the data set and managed to split it into positive and negative arrays. However I'm not sure what to do now or even what I am doing right to process the data for the classifier.

```
datasettrain = np.loadtxt("Adaboost-trainer.txt")

negtrain, postrain = np.delete(datasettrain[datasettrain[:,2] < 0],2,1), np.delete(datasettrain[datasettrain[:,2] > 0],2,1)

clf = Adaboost(n_clf=5)
clf.fit(postrain, negtrain)
```

I know I'm supposed to be inputting features and labels but surely the data has to be in a different format for that? as opposed to just a plain text file? at least I always received data that was just labeled with features and labels and I could input it just by splitting that data. Any thoughts on how someone might process just a regular text file into features and labels?

edit

```
 1.116574  0.157686  +1
-0.359096  0.653998  -1
 1.845620  0.873235  +1
-0.271484 -0.960392  -1
 0.304631  2.797998  +1
```

Comment: Can you provide an sample of what's in `Adaboost-trainer.txt`? And what you are trying to train the model to classify, e.g. your target?

Comment: I'm trying to setup a boundary using weak classifiers using adaptive boosting. I've provided a sample of the data I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, if I'm interpreting your sample data correctly, the first two columns are your feature columns and the last column is your target values. If this is correct, then to get training and test sets, you would need to do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.loadtxt("Adaboost-trainer.txt")

# Determine your training/test split. I opted for 80/20
test_size = 0.2
split_index = int(data.shape[0] * test_size)

# Get the full train and test splits
indices = np.random.permutation(data.shape[0])
test_idx = indices[split_index:]
train_idx = indices[:split_index]
test = data[test_idx,:]
train = data[train_idx,:]

# Split the X and y for use in models
y_train = train[:,-1]
X_train = np.delete(train, 2, axis=1)
y_test = test[:,-1]
X_test = np.delete(test, 2, axis=1)
```

From there, you have an 80/20 train/test split of your data for use with a model.